# Switch active tabs with Selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I have developed this code which is used to open all search results into new tab:

```
String selectLinkOpeninNewTab = Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, Keys.RETURN);
results.get(i).sendKeys(selectLinkOpeninNewTab);

for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++)
{
    ArrayList<String> tabs2 = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles());
    driver.switchTo().window(tabs2.get(1));
    driver.close();
    driver.switchTo().window(tabs2.get(0));
}
```

what I want is when I open all tabs with search results I want to switch between all tabs with 2 seconds delay.

How I can implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code,

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class TabSwitching {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, AWTException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:/WorkSpace/Driver/chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

        driver.get("http://www.google.com/xhtml");
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        WebElement searchBox = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
        searchBox.sendKeys("Software testing");
        searchBox.submit();

        System.out.println("Current Url: " + driver.getCurrentUrl());

        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("h3.r a")));

        List<WebElement> results = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//h3[@class='r']/a"));

        for (WebElement ele : results) {
            String selectLinkOpeninNewTab = Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, Keys.RETURN);
            ele.sendKeys(selectLinkOpeninNewTab);
        }
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        ArrayList<String> tabs2 = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles());
        System.out.println(tabs2.size());

        for (int i = tabs2.size()-1; i>=0; i--) {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            driver.switchTo().window(tabs2.get(i));
            Robot robot = new Robot();

            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
            System.out.println(driver.getTitle() + "i: " + i);
            driver.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tabs are closed one by one but I want to switch the active tabs.

Comment: Looks like there is a bug in Chrome and it's not working properly.

Comment: Hai that is because i have programmed it that way. its not a bug in chrome

Comment: Instead of  driver.close(); do something else which you want.

Comment: Ok, i remove it but still it's not working.

Comment: add some action in it. When you just removed the driver.close(); nothing will happen. Just added some action like verify an element in it.

Comment: Can you show me some example please?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115842/discussion-between-selva-and-peter-penzov).