# Focus on recent open tab using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have one website in which When I `click` on button, it open new tab with link in same browser.

I want to tell selenium to focus on that recently open tab.

I tried many methods but none of them seem helpful in my case.

I have tried :

**Method 1 :**

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL);
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
```

**Method 2 :**

```
((JavascriptExecutor) webDriver).executeScript("window.focus();");
```

**Method 3:**

```
driver.switchTo().window(driver.getWindowHandles().last());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38074943/switch-active-tabs-with-selenium/38075186#38075186), use Java Robot. that worked for me.

```
ArrayList<String> tabs2 = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles());
        System.out.println(tabs2.size());

        for (int i = tabs2.size()-1; i>=0; i--) {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            driver.switchTo().window(tabs2.get(i));
            Robot robot = new Robot();

            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
            System.out.println(driver.getTitle() + "i: " + i);
           // do what you needed
        }
```